# UITableViewController Static and Grouped scrollToRowAtIndexPath not scrolling to correct cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` in which I am using Static Cells that are grouped. Each cell has a `UITextField` for users to enter info, and at the bottom is a submit button. Upon tapping the button, I verify that they have entered info for each of the fields and if not, I scroll up to that cell/field so that they can complete it.

However, for some reason it is not scrolling to the correct cell when using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`:

```
#pragma mark - Save

- (IBAction)didTapSaveGuestDetails:(ZSSBottomOverlayButton *)sender {

    [self checkForFormSubmissionErrors];

}

- (void)checkForFormSubmissionErrors {

    // First Name
    if (self.nameFirst.text.length == 0) {
        [self showAlertWithMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"* Please enter first name", nil) fieldToHighlight:self.nameFirst];
        return;
    }

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self submitUpdatedGuestInfo];

}

- (void)submitUpdatedGuestInfo {



}


#pragma mark - Alert

- (void)showAlertWithMessage:(NSString *)message fieldToHighlight:(UIView *)field {

    UIColor *redColor = [OTAColors colorWithRed:234 green:85 blue:58];
    [RKDropdownAlert title:message backgroundColor:redColor textColor:[UIColor whiteColor] time:2.0];

    if (field) {

        [self highlightField:field];

    }

}

- (void)highlightField:(UIView *)field {

    [self.tableView endEditing:YES];

    // Color field
    if ([field isKindOfClass:[ZSSLargeTextField class]]) {
        ZSSLargeTextField *textField = (ZSSLargeTextField *)field;
        [textField showWarning];
    }

    CGPoint pointInTable = [field convertPoint:field.bounds.origin toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTable];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];

}
```

This exact implementation works great when using prototype cells, but NOT static.

However, if I use the following it does scroll to the correct cell:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

So, it seems the issue could be in my `convertPoint:toView:` method?

**Any idea what could be preventing it from scrolling to the correct cell?**

Comment: Try setting `pointInTable ` equal to a point you know is in the correct NSIndexPath and see if it still scrolls to the wrong cell.